# SEARCH BAR WITH EXPRESS AND MONGO

Tags: mongodb, express

I have created a form where the user can submit some information to my mongoDB database. I would like to have a search bar where the user can search for the info from my database.

I was thinking that using Model.find() in some way, would work?

Any suggestions for how this is accomplished would be very appreciated:) I would also like to have the search results appear below the search bar in a list.

PLZZ GIVE ME CODE...

Answer (score 0):

yes it works but use regex some times character comes in request may be in upper or lower case
query :

```
model.find({'fieldname' : {$regex : 'value', $options : 'i'}})
```